# display array in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I have an array with 2 questions: I want do show all the questions in textarea in my HTMl. But when I click the button, It only shows the last question. In "console.log" it does show the whole array.
Why?
Html part:

```
<button id = "vragen">Questions:</button> <br><br>
    <textarea name="" id="input"></textarea><br><br>
```

then, js part:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var questions=
    [
    {
    vraag: "Como voce se chama?\n (a)Pedro\n(b)Fred\n(c)Douglas",           
     answer:"a"
     
    },
    {
        vraag:"Qual sua idade? \n(a)25\n(b)30\n(c)39",
        
        answer: "c"
    }
    
];

vraag.addEventListener("click",quiz);
function quiz()

{
 for(var i = 0; i< questions.length;i++)
 {
     var vragen = questions[i].vraag;  
     input.value = vragen;     
     console.log(vragen);
 }
```

help please.

Comment: change `input.value = vragen` to `input.value += vragen`.

Comment: change **vraag.addEventListener("click",quiz);** with **document.getElementById('vragen').addEventListener("click", quiz);**

Comment: and add a couple of line breaks - see my answer.

Comment: How are you going to read the user's answer?
With `textarea` - you're just setting yourself for a lot of work...
Try with `div`s and `buttons`...

Comment: I am just trying, steb by step to finish this quiz project. Any suggestions for setting users choices?

Comment: You can use radio or buttons, for example.
Do you want user to select answers first, then evaluate all questions, or, 
do you want user to press the answer choice button and be informed immediately if right or wrong?

Comment: Do you want to randomize choice answers or always show in same order?
If randomize, questions array should hold question, choice answers, and the correct answer - [["answer 1", true],["answer 2", false]...] or [{answer:"answer 1",correct:true},{answer:"answer 2",correct:false}...].

Comment: Do you want "Click to show questions" button, or show questions (and multiple answers) right away?

Comment: `var questions = [
  {
    vraag: "Como voce se chama?",
    options: ["(a) Pedro", "(b) Fred", "(c) Douglas"],
    answer: "(a) Pedro"
  },{
    vraag: "Qual sua idade?",
    options: ["(a) 25", "(b) 30", "(c)39"],
    answer: "(c) 39"
  }
];`

Comment: `var questions = [
  {
    vraag: "Como voce se chama?",
    options: ["Pedro", "Fred", "Douglas"],
    answer: "Pedro"
  },{
    vraag: "Qual sua idade?",
    options: ["25", "30", "39"],
    answer: "39"
  }
];` and take care of a/b/c... in code

Comment: `var questions = [
  {
    vraag: "Como voce se chama?",
    options: [["Pedro", true], ["Fred", false], ["Douglas", false]]
  },{
    vraag: "Qual sua idade?",
    options: [["25", false], ["30", false], ["39", true]]
  }
];`

Comment: `var questions = [
  {
    vraag: "Como voce se chama?",
    options: [{option:"Pedro", correct:true}, {option:"Fred", correct:false}, {option:"Douglas", correct:false}]
  },{
    vraag: "Qual sua idade?",
    options: [{option:"25", correct:false}, {option:"30", correct:false], {option:"39",correct: true}]
  }
];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var vragen = document.getElementById("vragen");
var questions = [
  {
    vraag: "Como voce se chama?\n(a)Pedro\n(b)Fred\n(c)Douglas",           
    answer:"a"
  },{
    vraag: "Qual sua idade? \n(a)25\n(b)30\n(c)39",
    answer: "c"
  }
];

vragen.addEventListener("click",quiz);

function quiz() {
  for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    var vraag = questions[i].vraag;  
    input.value += vraag + "\n\n";     
    console.log(vraag);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id = "vragen">Questions:</button><br><br>
<textarea name="" id="input" rows=12 cols=40></textarea><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

> input.value = vragen;

Don't assign instead append it.